# Are centre of symmetry(COS) and alternate axis of symmetry(AAOS) dependent on each other?

Tags: stereochemistry, symmetry, optical-properties

COS=Centre of symmetery
AAOS=Alternate axis of symmetry

Lets suppose a molecule has a COS. Does it need to have AAOS?

What about the converse? If a molecule has AAOS does it necessarily have a COS?

With some research and help I can see that having AAOS doesn't mean it has COS. Still problem with the 1st question does COS imply AAOS?

Comment: What is your reasoning, e.g. after passing both tutorial and _the interactive gallery_ of Symmetry @ Otterbein, http://faculty.otterbein.edu/djohnston/sym/index.html?  Selecting 18-crown-6 in the section $S_n$ (http://faculty.otterbein.edu/djohnston/sym/gallery/index.html), for example, allows you to (pan, rotate, zoom) the molecules, to toggle on/off the display the symmetry elements, to launch their operation -- and if the sequence is too fast, to use a slider to see the intermediate (marked in yellow) at any stage between $E$ and the operation applied.

Comment: @Buttonwood thanks man that helped a lot... Now I understand the difference they cause... Visualising without any add is difficult.